# Some questions about constructor chaining in C++

Tags: c++, constructor

Can i call a constructor within a member function ?Is it an example of constructor chaining?
Is constructor chaining valid in the latest C++ version?(like what we have in C#)

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349183/constructor-chaining-in-c

Comment: You can call constructors and desctructors directly, but I would be careful with that. Are you trying to achieve something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494471/c-is-it-possible-to-call-a-constructor-directly-without-new ?

Comment: @MarcusRiemer:No,I read that constructor chaining was invalid in c++ i just wanted to know if it is supported lately or not, and i also wanted to know if i could call a constructor from a member function or not.The link minus posted has the most simarilty to my question (actually my question was raised because of the same article, app asked about.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Yes

2) No, calling a constructor from a function is not constructor chaining.

3) Yes, it is called [Delegating Constructors](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/b-5-delegating-constructors/)

Comment: 1) probably not in the sense he intends (calling a constructor on your own object)